# Webpage / Other application does not fit fully on screen

Tags: display

I have an ASUS Eee PC 1008 HA

The problem is that I have to move the cursor up/down in order to see the start control / icons at the bottom of the screen and the cursor up in order to see the menu bar / etc at the top of the screen, ie the whole page does not fit on the screen anymore.

It has nothing to do with the zoom % in the bottom right hand corner. This also is the case whatever application I am running, ie Internet explorer , word, excel or whatever. Does anybody have an idea what is the problem and how I can resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

You have a screen resolution that is bigger than your actual screen. Set it to the resolution that your computer actually have (probably 1024x600).

Comment: You mean it's lower ;) You can't raise the screen resolution above the native resolution.

Comment: @Tobias - Sure you can. My Asus EEE allows me to set the the screen resolution to 1024x700, but since the screen is only 1024x600 I get the same result as Frank get. I have to scroll down a bit to see the taskbar andu up a bit to see the menues of a maximized window.

Comment: Two things:
1. That's weird.
2. Guess I was wrong, then ;)

Comment: A lot of the netbooks do this.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely have the screen resolution set higher than your display resolution.

Open Control Panels → Display → Settings, and reduce your screen resolution.